# Multiple regressions

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, model-selection

Consider that we have two independent datasets $(Y_1, X_1)^\top, \dots, (Y_{n_1}, X_{n_1})^\top$, and the second denoted as $(Y`_1, X`_1)^\top, \dots, (Y`_{n_2}, X`_{n_2})^\top$. We assume that the first dataset is iid and follows a linear model (with possibly non-normal noise), and also that the second dataset is iid and follows a linear model (with possibly non-normal noise).

I am looking for a test that says if those two linear models are the same. By "the same" I mean that the regression coefficients are the same AND the noise distributions are the same. Do you have maybe some reference which deals with such a problem?

I only found this reference
[http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~nchristo/statistics100C/testing_equations_paper.pdf](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/%7Enchristo/statistics100C/testing_equations_paper.pdf) but it only deals with testing if the regression coefficients are the same (while assuming a normal noise).

Comment: Are you interested in testing if they're *different* (ie, the standard approach), or if they're the *same* (an equivalence test?

Comment: Null hypothesis is that the regression models are the same. Does it answer your question?